# PDO Loop images within a looped modal

Tags: php, pdo

Desired result: Loop an equivalent amount of modals as ID's within my database table1 whilst successfully looping images from table2 within those looped modals.

Current result: Loop one modal **period** whilst looping all images from table2 inside that one successful modal.

What do, and how?

```
                    <?php 

                    include("dbconfig.php");

                    /*include("class.user.php");*/
                    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
                    $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
                    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment_imgs");
                    $stmt->execute();


                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $date = $row['date'];
                    $comment = $row['comment']; 
                    $project_id = $row['project_id'];
                    $display_id = $row['display_id'];
                    $user_name = $row['user_name'];

                ?>                  
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" id="display">
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $project_id;?></h5>
                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $date;?></p>
                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $user_name;?></p>
                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $comment;?></p>
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo $id;?>" id="formButtons">
                              Button
                            </button>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?php echo $id;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModal<?php echo $id;?>Label"><?php echo $project_id;?></h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                    <?php echo $date;?>
                                    <?php echo $comment;?>
                                    <?php echo $user_name;?>
                                    <?php

                                            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM uploads");
                                            $stmt->execute();


                                            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                                            {
                                            $image_path = $row["image_path"]."/".$row["image_name"];
                                            $display_id = $row['display_id'];

                                    ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $image_path; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" class="images" /></a><?php } ?>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
                                            <?php
                        }
                ?>
    </div>
```

table1:
[Table 1 (comment_imgs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTPOm.png)

table2:[Table 2 (Uploads)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdsNt.png)

Comment: you are using twice the same var `$stmt` for the 2 requests. The second one overwrites the first, and because all the rows are already extracted in the inner loop, the main loop ends for no more row to fetch. (you are also using `$row` twice, which has currently no effect, but should also be changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the result variable `$stmt` in inner loop to something else, since you are overwriting the variable with which you are iterating.

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment_imgs");
$stmt->execute();


       $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM uploads");
       $stmt->execute();
       // the variable result is overwritten
```